# Help me find the best of WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, user-interface

I would like to find what people got the most out of using WPF, in particular:

- The best and stunning UI examples out there
- Dark corners that no other UI can implement with ease and style (say MFC or GTK)
- Professional examples with code

Suggestions?

Probably the best book on the subject is [WPF in Action with Visual Studio 2008](http://manning.com/feldman2/)

Comment: Probably because it's not really worded like a question.

Comment: Still sounds more like a book recommendation than a question.

Comment: No book recommendation dude.... I just cited what I have read....

Comment: There are tons of similar questions...

Comment: Communists STOP CLOSING MY TOPICS....STOP NOW... IGNORE THEM IF YOU DON'T LIKE IT

Answer (score 3, accepted):

see: http://windowsclient.net/

especially: [HealtCare demo](http://windowsclient.net/downloads/folders/wpfsamples/entry3754.aspx)

Answer (score 5):

Here's some of my favorites:

- [Family.Show](http://www.vertigo.com/familyshow.aspx) - An genealogy application (with code)
  [image: Family.Show]
  <sub>(source: [blogcasts.de](http://blogcasts.de/dwalzen/blog/FamilyShow.png))</sub>
- [PhotoSuru](http://www.photosuru.com/) - A photo browser (with code)
  [image: PhotoSuru]
  <sub>(source: [photosuru.com](http://www.photosuru.com/default_files/image002.jpg))</sub>
- [Eikos Partners Products](http://72.32.149.120/index.html) - Just screenshots, but looks really nice
  [EP Trading http://72.32.149.120/screens/EP9.jpg](http://72.32.149.120/screens/EP9.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend checking WPF samples that come with Microsoft Expression Blend.

Answer (score 1):

[thirteen23.com](http://www.thirteen23.com)

THey have quite a lot of stunning interface work, but they actively let people download 2 or 3 of their projects at any one time... they kill the dl links for one's they're not currently working on whici is a shame